# How many subjects are there in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, nouns, subjects

In this sentence:

> **The "No"** was stronger than **her craving** to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence.

Did I distinguish all subjects in the sentence? Can it be that **her craving** is a complex subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subject of the sentence is:

- The "No"

However, the complement of the preposition *than* is the noun phrase:

- her craving to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence.

This has a co-ordination of clauses which appears as the complement of the noun *craving*.

The coordination of clauses is:

- to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence.

The unexpressed subject of these is 'her', whoever that is.

To sum up there is only one subject of the sentence: "The "No". However, there is a coordination of verb phrases which have *her* as the unexpressed subject of these clauses, not the subject of the sentence.

The noun phrase *her craving* is not a subject. *Craving* is the head of the noun phrase: "*her craving to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence*". This noun phrase is the complement of *than*.

*Hope this is helpful!*

**EDIT**: Some readers might wonder whether *craving* is a verb here. In my opinion it isn't. I explain why in a different post below (because the explanation's quite long!)

Comment: +1. :) I wonder if you could possibly add a bit to explain why you think "craving" cannot be a verb?

Comment: @F.E. Have done my best (might be wrong though!)

Answer (score 3):

**Extra commentary for grammar junkies**:

Some people might argue that *craving* is a verb here. There are some good reasons to think that maybe *craving* should be a verb. It isn't, in my opinion, in the normal reading of the sentence. We can do some tests to show this. There is a noun *craving*. If this is the noun *craving* we should expect it to be modifiable by an adjective:

- The "No" was stronger than her urgent craving to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence.

The sentence above seems ok.

Now if *craving* was a verb in the sentence above, it would be modified by an adverb *urgently*. Now, that sentence would work with the verb form too:

- The "No" was stronger than her urgently craving to be in Frisco's arms and forget this dreary existence.

This sentence seems ok as well.

The clue to the status of *craving* is in the grammar. The verb *crave* is very difficult to use without an object:

- Elephants crave.

The sentence above is possible, but very unusual. It would be unusual in the same way that:

- Elephants like.

... would be unusual. We normally expect these verbs to have an object. If we don't have an object this use of these verbs is very unusual, very marked. However, the use of *craving* as a noun without any complement is commonplace:

- Cravings are very inconvenient when you are trying to concentrate.

The Original Poster's sentence seems quite ordinary when there is no complement for the word *craving*:

- The "No" was stronger than her craving.

In addition to the other evidence, this would seem to suggest that *craving* is a noun. Notice that:

- The "No" was stronger than her liking.

... is a bit strange when given the normal meaning of the verb *LIKE*.

Lastly, notice that if we use *craving* modified by an adjective, but without a complement, the result is good and not marked:

- The "No" was stronger than her urgent craving.

However, if we substitute the noun *craving* with a verb modified by an adverb, the result is not very good:

- *The "No" was stronger than her urgently craving. (X)

The result above is very similar to the *to her liking* example.